# How are the steps to the solution for Arc - Length obtained?

Tags: vectors, proof-explanation, calculus-of-variations, parametric, arc-length

Can someone please help me follow and understand the steps of the solution marked with $(*)$ and $(@)$? Why is the dot product used and computed with the unit vector. How does this equal the integral? I'm not sure where these steps are coming from.

**Example:**

Show that in $\mathbb{R}^n$, the length of any parametric curve connecting **a** and **b** is at least as long as the length of the straight line connecting the points with position vectors **a** and **b**.

**Solution:**

For a parametric curve with $I = [a,b]$ and **x**(a) = **a** and **x**(b) = **b** and for a unit vector **u** we have the inequality $$({\bf{b}-{\bf{a}}})\cdot {\bf{u}} = \int_a^b \dot {{\bf{x}}} \cdot {\bf{u}} {\it{dt}} ≤\int_ b ^a |\dot{\bf{x}}|dt \quad (*)$$

as $\dot{\bf{x}}·{\bf{u} = |\dot{x}||u|}\cosθ ≤| {\bf{\dot{x}}}||{\bf{u}}| = |\ {\bf{\dot{x}}}|$, and by taking
$${\bf{u}} =\frac{
{\bf{b−a} }}{{\bf{|b−a|}}} \quad @$$
we obtain that
$$|{\bf{b−a}}|≤\int_{b}^ a |\dot{\bf{ x}}| dt = L $$so that the length of the curve is at least **|b−a|**.

Comment: Gosh... isn't "the shortest path between two points is a straight line," proved 2500 years ago, sufficient?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The problem is, this is the calculus of variations. Intuition needs to be proved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot product is taken because you want to estimate the length $|{\bf b} - {\bf a}|$.

Now:

$$|{\bf b} - {\bf a}|^2 = ({\bf b}-{\bf a}) \cdot ({\bf b} - {\bf a})$$

Thus:

$$|{\bf b} - {\bf a}| = \frac{({\bf b}-{\bf a}) \cdot ({\bf b} - {\bf a}) }{ |{\bf b} - {\bf a}|} = ({\bf b}-{\bf a}) \cdot {\bf u}$$

Note that the unit vector $\bf{u}$ is constant. If you spell out the inner product, you'll get

$$
\int_a^b {\dot{\bf{x}}} {\cdot} {\bf{u}} \, dt = 
\int_a^b \sum_{i=1}^n \frac {dx_i(t)} {dt} u_i \, dt =
\sum_{i=1}^n u_i \int_a^b \frac {dx_i(t)}{dt} dt
$$

The integral on the right amounts to the total difference $x_i(b) - x_i(a)$. Thus,

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n u_i \int_a^b \frac {dx_i(t)}{dt} dt = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i \, (b_i - a_i) = {\bf u} \cdot ({\bf b} - {\bf a})
$$